# Delphi Compiling, no error, but then nothing happens

Tags: delphi, compiler-errors

I have made a program with multiple forms. When I run the program it compiles but nothing happens at all I stay in the IDE.

I presume it is because it doesn't know which form to show first. I have checked and made the one I want to show first visible = true however this hasn't changed anything.

This is the code on the project part:

```
program Project1
uses
forms,
SQLUnit in 'SQLUnit.pas',
Entrance in 'Entrance.pas',
Addpop in 'Addpop.pas',
Home in 'Home.pas',
Quiz2 in 'Quiz2.pas',
Teacher in 'Teacher.pas',
Userclass in 'Userclass.pas',
Stat in 'Stat.pas',
Typesofclasses in 'Typesofclasses.pas',
TimeDisplay in 'TimeDisplay.pas',
Quiz1 in 'Quiz1.pas',
Timetableclass in 'Timetableclass.pas';

{$R *.res}

begin
Application.Initialize;
Application.MainFormOnTaskbar := True;
Application.Run;
end.
```

I presume this is the most relevant however I am unsure. I have looked it up and someone had a vageuly similar problem and said they solved it with auto-create. I have tried to find this in my program but can't find where I would set it up or where it is

Comment: I'm very curious how you managed to break your project in such a way in the first place. That unit is automatically constructed by Delphi, and creating the main form should already be there by default when you create a brand new project. The only way it could be missing is if someone explicitly deleted it, which is plausible, since I see the indentation and line breaks are not the default either. You shouldn't modify this unit so openly, the IDE "owns" it.

Comment: @JerryDodge I haven't modified it at all. The indention is because I copy and pasted it.

Comment: Well, Stack Overflow has always retained indentation just fine, and there's no way it removed line breaks (before `uses`) from that file either. This file has definitely been modified by someone. During that modification, my guess is that for some reason, the `CreateForm` line got removed. It's well known that trying to add code to this file can cause the IDE to scramble the code, requiring someone to fix it back up. So I really feel that some information is being left out here which points to the true cause. Also, `forms` isn't capitalized as default, so yes, this *has* been modified.

Comment: @JerryDodge I coppied it straight from the file. I coppied it by hand because I wasn't sure about the stack overflow method for making it look like the code part.

Comment: Okay, but still, there are numerous signs that tell me yes, someone definitely modified this file. The IDE doesn't change `Forms` to `forms`, it doesn't remove the line break before `uses`, and it certainly doesn't remove the creation of the main form.

Comment: @RosieMurphy: the code doesn't look like code that was directly created or modified by the IDE, so *someone* must have edited it manually and in that process, probably one or more `CreateForm` lines were removed too. The IDE doesn't remove empty lines, it doesn't write `forms`, it doesn't indent like that, and it doesn't remove semicolons (after `program Project1`) etc. That code doesn't even compile.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The project file need at least one Application.CreateForm for the main form in your application.

```
program Project1
uses
forms,
SQLUnit in 'SQLUnit.pas',
Entrance in 'Entrance.pas',
Addpop in 'Addpop.pas',
Home in 'Home.pas',
Quiz2 in 'Quiz2.pas',
Teacher in 'Teacher.pas',
Userclass in 'Userclass.pas',
Stat in 'Stat.pas',
Typesofclasses in 'Typesofclasses.pas',
TimeDisplay in 'TimeDisplay.pas',
Quiz1 in 'Quiz1.pas',
Timetableclass in 'Timetableclass.pas';

{$R *.res}

begin
Application.Initialize;
Application.MainFormOnTaskbar := True;
Application.CreateForm(TMainForm, MainForm);
Application.Run;
end.
```

You can just enter the missing line or use Project | Options | Forms to select it.

[image: Select Main form under options]

Comment: I tried to do the automated process but there were no avaliable forms?

Comment: Are any of the units shown in the project file forms?

Comment: None are in the avaliable section or in the drop down main form section.

Comment: Use Project | Add to project to add the main form or create a new one

Comment: @JanLauridsen Thank you! Should I add all the other forms I have as well (but not make them the main form)?

Comment: Yes all the forms used by the projects should be added. Only the main form should be auto created. If there are data modules they should be auto created too.

Comment: @JanLauridsen Your last comment is bad advice. What should / should not be auto-created depends on requirements and design. There are no hard and fast rules in this regard. As for adding forms that don't need to be auto-created: strictly speaking the compiler is capable of finding them depending on where they are located. However, I would strongly recommend adding them explicitly. Being explicit avoids confusion and means the compiler doesn't have to "search".

Comment: @Craig Young. You are of course right. What I meant with "should" is what I would recommend for a new project.

Answer (score 0):

Here's something weird that I have come across:

I have experienced the same issue twice today. Both times have involved the TPageControl. It seems as if somehow selecting the tab in the design window before running solves the issue - almost as if Delphi had somehow forgotten which tabsheet to load.

I know this is a bit late to the party, but hey - maybe it will help someone else in future.